# Field is never assigned to, and will always have its default value

Tags: c#, oop

I'm making a small game for school and I want to make a list with instances from the class Bricks. So I did this.

```
 public class Game1 : Game
    {
        public static SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

        private GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        private WreckingBall          _wreckingBall;
        private MouseHandler          _mouse;
        private bool                  _drag;

        private List<Brick> _bricks;
```

But now the compiler says "Field 'WreckingBall.Game1._bricks' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null"

This is my Brick class

```
class Brick : DrawableGameComponent
    {
        public Texture2D _texture { get; set; }
        public Vector2 _position { get; set; }


         public Brick(Game game)
            : base(game)
        {
            Game.Components.Add(this);
            this._position = _position;
        }

         protected override void LoadContent()
         {
             _texture = Game.Content.Load<Texture2D>("Brick");

             base.LoadContent();
         }

         public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
         {
             _position = new Vector2(100, 100);

             base.Update(gameTime);
         }

         public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
         {
                 Game1.spriteBatch.Draw(_texture, _position, Color.White);

             base.Draw(gameTime);
         }

    }
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is compiler wrong? You have never assigned it indeeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere in your code you need:

```
_bricks = new List<Brick>();
```

A good place for it is in the constructor, but you can even initialize the list in the private variables section:

```
private List<Brick> _bricks = new List<Brick>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Instantiate it in `Game`:

```
private List<Brick> _bricks = new List<Brick>();
```

Comment: Oh wow. Been looking at my own code for too long to see such a stupid mistake. Thanks for your help.